# How to change php version in Blue host?

Tags: php, cpanel, shared-hosting, php-5.6

I changed php version in my Bluehost 5.4 to 5.6  my php info page changed as 5.6 but when i check via commandline its showing 5.2 version 
you can check this - [LINK](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByoLPyyQ3jAjaHZzdTZwTUlHLUU)

i used  this [LINK](https://box6114.bluehost.com:2083/cpsess6159589228/frontend/bluehost/cptt/phpconfig.html?post_login=11238011977742)  but i don't know how to ignore master php version 5.2 and add 5.6

Comment: system has changed version 5.6 but when i check via ssh key only showing 5.2

Comment: yes its correct but when i check via ssh comandline its shwoing 5.2

Comment: And that is important because? You know it is using the version set in cpanel. Ok, the ssh command line is confused - maybe it doesn't look in the cpanel stuff. You don't care as long as it uses the selected PHP version in your PHP scripts. :). Forget about it and write some code? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can access 5.6 via
`/usr/php/56/bin/php`

Comment: It does. He's asking how to access the PHP version that his site is running on from the command line.  This is how you do it, you can alias it or add it to your path if you want to "change" to it, but this is how you access it.

Answer (score 0):

The version that you see in the php info file is the one that your account is actually using and this is the version that your scripts will use and will be executed with.

The reason why you see a different version via SSH is due to the way their server is set up and the PHP Selector works. This is common with other webhosting providers as well.

Comment: my requirements is install composer in my hosting via putty for that i need 5.6 access

Comment: Is this shared hosting or VPS?

Comment: Shared Hosting @Jason